# How to execute ABC at runtime? (use AS2 inside AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Can I execute ActionScript 2.0 (AS2) ByteCode at runtime inside an AS3 project?

I tried to find it through Google search, but I didn't find an answer.

For example, I need a function that works like this:

```
executeByteCode(myByteCode);
```

Comment: Maybe put the code in an SWF and then `load` the SWF. That should execute your code as stored in the SWF. You can check the [**SWF** Format Specification](http://wikil.lwwhome.cn:28080/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) for understanding where in the SWF bytes to add your ABC. You are looking for the **DoABC** tag (read up on it).

Comment: Alternatively just compile the original AS3 code (that generated your bytecode) into an SWF and then access the code's vars/function from the SWF. Bytecode is from compilation, so why not just use the compiled SWF (instead of extracting bytecode from it and then looking for a `executeByteCode` method)?

Comment: It's because my swf, which I need to load is AS2 (DoAction), not DoABC, and I can't load it.

Comment: You **cannot mix** AS2 bytecode into an AS3 Project (is different VM versions). You can load an AS2-based SWF using AS3 but you cannot access its vars/function. If you need those AS2 functions the only way is to **re-write them in AS3**. If you don't know/have the original code you can try a using a decompiler (though this is best only if you are already familiar with original code and now need hints when recreating).

Comment: The original code can be dynamically replaced at the server side.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're telling (or asking) me with server-side comment... Are you compiling server-side from AS code (text) into an SWF? or is server comment about something else? Anyways I'm telling you AS1/2 both use AVM version 1 and AS3 uses AVM version 2. The two versions are re-designs and not compatible with each other, so code that talks to AVM1 cannot be mixed with code that is for AVM2. Solution: Re-write the AS2 code as AS3, use in main project or compile it to external SWF then run the SWF from your main Flash project (which can now access that loaded SWF's functions).